# Populate listbox from a selected.item in another listbox

Tags: winforms, powershell, listbox

Good day to you all!

I have a Powershell program that I am making for my company. I have 2 listbox, one with the make of printers and the other will be for the models of printers. I was hoping for help to populate the 'model' list with what the user selects in the 'make' list. I understand doing a selecteditem could work, but whatever I do, it doesn't populate the 'model' list.

This is my first time programming and am self-taught. Right now, I am using Windows.Forms to make the GUI.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much for this wonderful community of like-minded awesomeness!

*Code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Form_Service = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form_Service.ClientSize = '452,400'
$Form_Service.text = "Service Call"
$Form_Service.TopMost = $true
$Form_Service.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$Label_ValleyID = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label_ValleyID.text = "Enter Valley ID"
$Label_ValleyID.AutoSize = $true
$Label_ValleyID.width= 25
$Label_ValleyID.height = 10
$Label_ValleyID.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(45,41)
$Label_ValleyID.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$TextBox_ValleyID= New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox_ValleyID.multiline= $false
$TextBox_ValleyID.width= 180
$TextBox_ValleyID.height = 20
$TextBox_ValleyID.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(45,62)
$TextBox_ValleyID.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Label_Make= New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label_Make.text = "Make"
$Label_Make.AutoSize = $true
$Label_Make.width= 25
$Label_Make.height = 10
$Label_Make.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(45,108)
$Label_Make.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$ListBox_Make= New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$ListBox_Make.text = "Make"
$ListBox_Make.width= 144
$ListBox_Make.height = 50
$ListBox_Make.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(45,129)

[void] $ListBox_Make.Items.Add('Brother')
[void] $ListBox_Make.Items.Add('Canon')
[void] $ListBox_Make.Items.Add('HP')
[void] $ListBox_Make.Items.Add('Kyocera')
[void] $ListBox_Make.Items.Add('Ricoh')
[void] $ListBox_Make.Items.Add('Sharp')

$Label_Model = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label_Model.text= "Model"
$Label_Model.AutoSize= $true
$Label_Model.width = 25
$Label_Model.height= 10
$Label_Model.location= New-Object System.Drawing.Point(259,108)
$Label_Model.Font= 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$ListBox_Model = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$ListBox_Model.text= "Model"
$ListBox_Model.width = 146
$ListBox_Model.height= 50
$ListBox_Model.location= New-Object System.Drawing.Point(259,129)

$Label_Location= New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label_Location.text = "Location"
$Label_Location.AutoSize = $true
$Label_Location.width= 25
$Label_Location.height = 10
$Label_Location.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(45,195)
$Label_Location.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$TextBox_Location= New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox_Location.multiline= $false
$TextBox_Location.width= 363
$TextBox_Location.height = 20
$TextBox_Location.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(45,215)
$TextBox_Location.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Label_Problem = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label_Problem.text= "State what is wrong:"
$Label_Problem.AutoSize= $true
$Label_Problem.width = 25
$Label_Problem.height= 10
$Label_Problem.location= New-Object System.Drawing.Point(45,250)
$Label_Problem.Font= 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$TextBox_Problem = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox_Problem.multiline = $false
$TextBox_Problem.width = 364
$TextBox_Problem.height= 100
$TextBox_Problem.location= New-Object System.Drawing.Point(45,270)
$TextBox_Problem.Font= 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$CheckBox_Nope = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox_Nope.text= "Is your printer inoperable?"
$CheckBox_Nope.width = 250
$CheckBox_Nope.height= 50 
$CheckBox_Nope.location= New-Object System.Drawing.Point(145,295)
$CheckBox_Nope.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Button_Submit = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button_Submit.text= "Submit"
$Button_Submit.width = 70
$Button_Submit.height= 30
$Button_Submit.location= New-Object System.Drawing.Point(189,345)
$Button_Submit.Font= 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Form_Service.controls.AddRange(@($Label_ValleyID,$Label_Make,$Label_Model,$Label_Location,$Label_Problem,$TextBox_ValleyID,$ListBox_Make,$ListBox_Model,$TextBox_Location,$TextBox_Problem,$Button_Submit,$CheckBox_Nope))

if ($ListBox_Make.SelectedItem -eq "Brother"){
[void] $ListBox_Model.Items.Add('MP301')
}

[void]$Form_Service.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Please post your (relevant) code

Comment: updated. Check above

Comment: please format this code

Comment: Where is the code where you get the models?

Comment: I added the code to the bottom. And how do you mean format? I apologize for my arrogance. Like I said, I'm new and self-taught

Comment: I am self taught also. Dont worry about it i edited your post already. By format i mean i should be able to copy it and run it from my powershell without additional formatiing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so what you are looking for is called events. Events are actions that take place that then allow you to run code after the action. Like when Mouse Clicks on a object or Keyboard button is pressed.

In Powershell when dealing with Winforms you can use

```
$Control.Add_EventName{
    Code Here
}
```

Put the events after the controls are already called. I usally put them right before i show a form.

```
$ListBox_Make.Add_Click{
    $ListBox_Model.Items.Add($ListBox_Make.SelectedItem)
}

[void]$Form_Service.ShowDialog()
```

in your exact case you could use :

```
$ListBox_Make.Add_Click{
    if ($ListBox_Make.SelectedItem -eq "Brother"){
        [void] $ListBox_Model.Items.Add('MP301')
    }
}
```

Hopefully this puts you on the right track.

Also instead of a bunch of if Statements try a Switch instead

```
$ListBox_Make.Add_Click{
    switch ($ListBox_Make.SelectedItem){
        "Brother"{
            $ListBox_Model.Items.Add('MP301')
        }
        "Canon"{
            $ListBox_Model.Items.Add('LT45')
        }
        "HP"{
            $ListBox_Model.Items.Add('ABC2133')
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the events for listbox
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox?view=netframework-4.7.2#events

Comment: So, when you say "Code Here" after the $Control, which code are you referring to? The one I tried for selectedItem?

Comment: *Did not see you edited your answer* I tried to add the code and fine tune it, but cannot get it to work. I think I am not understanding something here;

    $Control.Add_Brother{
        $ListBox_Model.Items.Add("MP301")
        }


        if ($ListBox_Make.Add_Click -eq "Sharp"){
        $Control.Add_Brother
        }

I want to add certain items to the 'Model' list when 'Make' is selected, and each 'Make' will have different models...

Comment: Awesome! I was able to add another event of Items.Clear() before the addition to clear out the listbox before adding the appropriate models. Now, it should read across like I plan it would and the user can send us an email of what printer they are requesting assistance. Thank you so much ArcSet!

Comment: Anytime :) glad you learned from it. Remeber the Term Event. Because that what this was. The Event Was Click aka On Mouse Click. Each Control has its own events and you can also create custom events if needed.

Comment: ArcSet, might I message you privately about another question I asked last week? It is about inserting code into excel :/

Comment: I am guessing you are talking about [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52763832/type-mismatch-on-excel-data-from-powershell

Comment: Yes, it is that one. And I guess I cannot chat you until my rep is 20 (I am at 3)